# Rails Environment Variable PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, path

### Original Question:

I am on a Windows machine and I changed my PATH variable. Now I cannot run Rails commands such as rake db:migrate or bundle install etc.

Can someone please help me determine what I need the PATH variable to be so I can get these commands working again?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your answer as an answer instead of as an edit in you question, for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to append the following to my PATH variable:

C:\Ruby200-x64\bin (this is where all of the files such as rake and bundle are located)

Then I had to restart for the changes to take effect.